# hover effect on different classes in less

Tags: hover, less, siblings

I'm trying to have hover effects on two divs using less

```
<div class="uniforms">
    Image goes Here 
    <div class="textWrap">
        <div class="text">
                <div class="name">
                    Product Name Here
                </div>

                <div class="price">
                    Price Here
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>      
</div>
```

on hover over .uniforms I want to change the background color of .uniforms and the font color of .name  I have tried combinations of & ~ + ect but can not get the result I want

```
.uniforms{
    background-color: grey;
    padding: 10px;
    
    &:hover{
        background-color: red;
        
        ~ .name{
            color: white;
        }   
    }
}
```

I can do it with CSS but can't get it working with less.  Any help would be appreciated.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just remove ~

```
.uniforms{
    background-color: grey;
    padding: 10px;
    
    &:hover{
        background-color: red;        
        .name{
            color: white;
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: I've already tried that, the background changed but not the font color in .name

Answer (score 0):

Needed to be

```
.uniforms{
    background-color: grey;
    padding: 10px;
    
    &:hover{
        background-color: red;        
        .textWrap .name{
            color: white;
        }   
    }
}
```